# Should I go with ENUM or TINYINT

Tags: mysql

My table contains a field **'priority'**. Now I have following priorities to consider **'low', 'medium', 'high'.**

What I am confused with is that:

> 1. Should I create a ENUM type field for priority values ?
> 2. Should I create a TINYINT type field and store values as 1, 2, 3 ?

Please note I would be required **search and sort data** based on this field.
Also, there will be **indexing on this field**.

Answer (score 1):

You should use ENUM in case if you are sure none of the priority added in future because in that case you have to alter the table... BUt enum give surity of consistent data no other values gets inserted..

Answer (score 1):

You should go with ENUM, as you said you have to search / sort, stroing them in tiny int would make you to additional processing like convert 1,2,3 back to  'low', 'medium', 'high'. while displaying.

Enum is ideal for such situvations

Comment: Additional processing is not of big concern as I will be converting them on client side using js. My concern is the amount of data that will be stored in the table.  This table will get 100's of new entries per second so would it be wiser to go with TINYINT and reduce the amount of data stored in table?

Comment: `ENUM` types store character data only in the table definition, the value is actually stored as 1- or 2-byte integers in the actual records, so storage requirements are not a concern for your scenario: [reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html)

Comment: Thats correct ENUM types store character data only in the table definition

Answer (score 1):

**ENUM** is a non-standard MySql extension. You should avoid it, especially if you can achieve the same results in a standard way. So its better to go with **tinyint**.